# How many cards should be collected using the Mining Progress card?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

The Cities and Knights expansion to Settlers of Catan has two cards that have caused us a bit of disagreement.

[image: Mining and Irrigation Progress cards]

Take the Mining Progress card for example.  It says "...collect two ore for each mountain hex adjacent to one of your cities or settlements."  If I only have one settlement and one city and they are both adjacent to the same ore hex, should I collect two cards or four?  If you are to count mountain hex then it should be two, but if you are counting cities/settlements it should be four.

The same questions exists for the Irrigation Progress card.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You only collect two ore.**

The [4th edition cards](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?CaK_rv_Rules_091907.pdf)(pg. 15) contain updated text which makes this clear.

> You may take two ore cards from the bank for each mountain hex which is adjacent to at least one of your cities or settlements.

You can [purchase an updated card deck](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HBJ3HW).  I think this is all you need to update your set to the latest edition.

Answer (score -1):

It would count twice (so four ore) in your example if the rules would have stated `for each mountain hex adjacent to each of your cities or settlements`, unfortunately it doesn't and you have to pick one of your cities or settlements to process the cards for, which one is up to you.